# Count valid integers in a column of strings

Tags: python, pandas

How do I count elements in a column that are valid integers?

Here is what I have been able to come up with:

```
import re
pd.Series(["a","2","z","123","a","oops"]).apply(lambda x: x and re.match(r"^\d+$",x) and 1).sum()
==> 2.0
```

and

```
def isint (x):
    try:
        int(x)
        return 1
    except ValueError:
        return 0

pd.Series(["a","2","z","123","a","oops"]).apply(isint).sum()
==> 2
```

Obviously, the second approach is better (returns in `int`, easily generalizes to other types - `date`s, `float`s &c), but I wonder if there is a still better way that would not require me to write my own function.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `.str` attribute of series offers vectorized string methods:

```
>>> ser = pd.Series(["a","2","z","123","a","oops"])
>>> ser.str.isdigit().sum()
2
```

Answer (score 4):

i'd use [pd.to_numeric()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_numeric.html) method:

```
In [62]: pd.to_numeric(s, errors='coerce')
Out[62]:
0      NaN
1      2.0
2      NaN
3    123.0
4      NaN
5      NaN
dtype: float64

In [63]: pd.to_numeric(s, errors='coerce').count()
Out[63]: 2
```

Comment: Wouldn't this count floats too? No only integers?

Comment: @MikeMüller, yes, that's correct. So if OP want's to count only integers (ignoring floats), your solution is what he wants ;-) Sorry, can't upvote your solution one more time...

Comment: `(lambda x: (x == x // 1).sum())(pd.to_numeric(pd.Series(["a","2","z","123","a","oops"]), 'coerce'))`

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
isint = lambda x: all([ord(i) >= 48 and ord(i) < 58 for i in str(x)])
pd.Series(["a","2","z","123","a","oops"]).apply(isint).sum()
```